# cs50 mario less problem - my code is printing in a single line. I cant find whats wrong with it

Tags: cs50

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    do
    {
        n = get_int("Height: ");
    }
    while ((n < 1) || (n > 8));
for
    (int i = 0; i < n; i++)

    {for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
       if(i+j < n-1)
        printf(" ");
        else
        printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Prateek, is this an assignment/homework problem? Have you reached out to the respective discussion forum? If that isn't an option, and if it's ok to ask here - can you properly format your code before pasting here, show the current output, expected output, and in which part exactly you have doubt?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use `{}` to enclose codes blocks *for every* `for` loop and `if` conditional. This `printf("\n");` is *outside* both `for` blocks and thus prints exactly once. (The closing brace `}` before the final `printf` closes the code block of the `i` loop).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is formatted poorly which makes it hard for yourself:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int n;
    do {
        n = get_int("Height: ");
    } while ((n < 1) || (n > 8));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            if(i + j < n - 1)
                printf(" ");
            else
                printf("#");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

So you run you loops then print a single newline.  It's not clear if you want:

1. newline after each " " and "#":

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            printf("%c\n", i + j < n - 1 ? ' ' : '#');
```

2. newline for each 'i':

```
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            printf("%c", i + j < n - 1 ? ' ' : '#');
        printf("\n");
   }
```